# One repository my composer.json now empty or private I still wanted to use this composer.json how i add new repository

Tags: json, git, composer-php, sonata-media-bundle

this is my composer.json

```
{
"name": "mountain-code/symfony-sonata-media-admin",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},

"repositories": [
    {
    "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/sidz/SonataMediaBundle.git",
        "no-api": true
    }
],

"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.x-dev",
    "tilleuls/ckeditor-sonata-media-bundle": "^1.0",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^4.0",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~1.1",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.1",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3",
    "payum/offline": "^1.3",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.5.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

now

```
  "repositories": [
    {
    "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/sidz/SonataMediaBundle.git",
```

it s empty
But I still wanted to use this composer.json by adding another adcalendar repository
But when I make require adesigns / calendar-bundle no download for empty or private repository (https://github.com/sidz/SonataMediaBundle.git), as I can do thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. You referenced other peoples stuff in a way that specifically worked around their decision to NOT publish their work for the general public to consume. You didn't fork their repo or stored their work as a backup in any other way. And now it is gone.

The only thing that hopefully is left is the current state of the `vendor/sidz/SonataMediaBundle` directory with the last version that you were able to download before the deletion. You could start a new repository and commit this state into it and tag it with the same version, then switch the reference to this new repository. Composer only works by package name - if the name does not change (it is defined in the `composer.json` file you already have), and the version does not change, Composer consideres this package to be the same, even if the source URL is different.

You could also revert your dependency to be on the original package that is still maintained: https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/media-bundle I don't know how much has to change in your code in order to make that work, but I'd strongly suggest to go that route because otherwise you have to maintain that unofficial package yourself.

Comment: Fortunately I was at the end of my work only missing little things I solved by extending the bundles I already had, thanks